# Evaluating limit with 2 unknown parameters

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have another question involving limits with unknown parameters:
In this one, the limit approaches infinity:
$\lim \limits_{x \to 1 } {{\frac{x^2+ax+b}{(x-1)^2}}}= \infty $

This one is really causing me hardship, the only way i can see is to guess a function that would go to plus infinity that has a similar structure to this and choose the values of a and b, this way.

I was hoping there is another approach, some principle that can be used to figure this infinite limit out.

Comment: What happens when you approach 1 from the left and from the right?  Your denominator will always be positive and since its approaching 0, you have that structure figured out.  So the denominator is always positive.  What about values of a and b in the numerator?

Comment: What happens if $a=-2$ and $b=1$? By the way, what is it that you are supposed to do with this problem?  What is the question?

Comment: SO since the numerator is a quadratic function, for it to be positive, we would want to create a quadratic that has no real roots generally. But what about an edge case like setting a=b=0, we would get y = x^2 on numerator, this seems to work. Let me know if you have an opinion on this.

Comment: Hi Michael, if we set a = -2 and b = 1, then the numerator function = denominator function, so the limit would end up being 1, we want it to go to infinity.

Comment: With my values of a=b=0, the function limit will go to infinity, i graphed it on Desmos.

Comment: @Palu, does the answer below not address your concerns?

Comment: Hi, I was out, just got back, no internet. I briefly saw it, but had to go somewhere. I have to look at it in more detail, it is very thorough i have to say, very impressed with the amount of care and detail that went into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since evaluating at inputs close to 1 will produce an extremely small, but $\pmb{positive}$ denominator, we look at the numerator.

Case 1;  $1+a+b=0$

First, Replacing $x$ with 1 gives

$$1+a+b$$

Now, if $a=-2, b=1$, then $1+a+b=0$, the numerator and denominator are the same and the limit is 1.  The function doesn't exist at $x=1$, but does for all other $x$.

However, if there is an $a$ and $b$ such that the numerator is a product of $x-1$ and some other linear term, what happens?  Then the denominator acts like $x-1$ and not like $(x-1)^2$  This occurs, for example, when $a=-3$ and $b=2$.  If you divide $x^2+ax+b$ by $x-1$ you get

$$x^2+ax+b=(x-1)(x+a+1)+(a+b+1)$$

But since $a+b+1=0$, there is no remainder and your limit changes to

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{x+1+a}{x-1}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\left(1+\frac{a+2}{x-1}\right)$$

Thus, you can reduce the problem to finding the limit here:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{a+2}{x-1}=(a+2)\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{1}{x-1}$$

and this limit doesn't exist as left and right limits diverge.

Case 2: $1+a+b>0$

This is simple because then the numerator does not contain a factor of $x-1$ and since the numerator and denominator are positive when $x$ approaches 1, the limit increases without bound, i.e., $\infty$.

Case 3:  $1+a+b<0$

Same as case 2, but now the limit decreases without bound, $-\infty$.